# iRobot matlab simulator: robot getting stuck in wall boundaries and not moving anywhere

Tags: mobile-robot, matlab, irobot-create, sonar

I am using the iRobot Create simulator in matlab and I used sonar sensors on the robot for wall following but during the autonomous run but it got stuck in a corner. Please help me with this problem I read through the matlab documentation but got no clear solution. I have attached code and Output picture. Thanks in Advance!!

```
function TestProg_1(serPort)
    % Robot moves along a path, part blindly, part sensing.
    % serPort is the serial port number (for controlling the actual robot).
    
    disp ('==================')
    disp ('Program Starting  ')
    disp ('------------------')
    
    
    travelDist(serPort, .5, 4.5)% Move .5m/s (max. speed) for +2m
              % Speed in [.025,.5] meters/s
              % Positive distance means move forward
              % Negative distance means move backward
              % During this command nothing else is checked... no good
              %   to test sensor inputs, i.e. not possible to avoid walls!
    
    turnAngle(serPort, .5, 60)  % Turn at .2rad/s for +90 degrees
              % Speed in [.025,.2] radians/second
              % Positive angle means counter-clockwise
              % Negative angle means clockwise
    
    travelDist(serPort, .5, 2.5)
    turnAngle (serPort, .2, 90)
    
    % Read sonar value, out of range is returned as not a result! Hence
    %   needs checking. Using a real value larger than the map is one
    %   option to work with it, but no the only or necessarily the best!
    % sonar 1 is Left, 2 Front, 3 Right, 4 Rear.
    % Son(ar)FF(front sensor) will save the last value read in meters.
    SonFF = ReadSonar(serPort, 2)
    if ~any(SonFF) 
        SonFF = 100
    end
    
    %sets forward velocity using differential system
    SetDriveWheelsCreate(serPort, 0.4, 0.4)
    
    % Now check the sonar regularly while the robot moves,
    % till the distance in front drops below a desired value...
    while ( SonFF > 0.5)
        pause(.1)
        SonFF = ReadSonar(serPort, 2);
        if ~any(SonFF) 
            SonFF = 100;
        end
    end
    
    disp (SonFF)
    
    % stop the robot
    SetDriveWheelsCreate(serPort, 0, 0)
```

[image]